# React Dropdown Not Displaying Options

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a dropdown created with this statement:

```
<select
    id="personState"
    name="personState"
    className="form-control dropDownStyle"
    onChange={this.handleChange}
    value={this.props.person.personState}
>
    {this.state.stateCodes.map((option) => {
        <option key={option.id} value={option.data}>{option.data}</option>
    })}
</select>
```

With the debugger, I can see that `this.state.stateCodes` is getting populated with a two dimensional array that looks like this:

```
0:{id: 6408, data: "Arkansas"}
1:{id: 5555, data: "Wisconsin"}
```

However, no option values are getting added to the dropdown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is not quite right, in short, you're not returning the option element.

What you're doing is defining a function body for the anonymous function passed to your map, executing an expression (your  element), and returning undefined, as you have no return statement.

Naturally, to fix this you should add a return statement to your function body, or use a more concise syntax for the anonymous function passed to the map.

```
{this.state.stateCodes.map((option) => {

        //This is the function body, 
        <option key={option.id} value={option.data}>{option.data}</option>

       //We get here and return undefined, as you didn't return above.
    })}
```

You can use any of the following.

With the return statement. You could wrap the return statement value in parentheses if you wish.

```
{this.state.stateCodes.map((option) => {
     return <option key={option.id} value={option.data}>{option.data}</option>

})}
```

Without defining a function body, just defining the value to return.

```
{this.state.stateCodes.map((option) => <option key={option.id} value={option.data}>{option.data}</option>)}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to return the element inside [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) callback

```
{this.state.stateCodes.map((option) => {
    return (
     <option key={option.id} value={option.data}>{option.data}</option>
    )
})}
```

or just

```
{this.state.stateCodes.map((option) => (
    <option key={option.id} value={option.data}>{option.data}</option>
))}
```